# Is it possible to block thread access to 'A' while a thread is executing 'B'?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have two classes A and B

```
public class A
{
    public synchronized void doSomethingA
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public class B
{
    public synchronized void doSomethingB
    {
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

And i have two threads running in unison, let's call them x and y.

Since the methods are synchronized, it is not possible for y to access dosomethingA while x is in there, but it can access doSomethingA while x is doing doSomethingB.

Is there any way to block y from doing anything while x is in doSomethingA or in doSomethinB?

Comment: Note you lock an object not a method or a thread. If you want to block access to a locked object, obtain the lock first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of ways. The most direct way would be to use a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)`.

It provides the same functionality as `synchronized`, but you are responsible for managing the locking yourself. You'll need to share one between the classes, so that both methods can then use it for locking.

Comment: Thanks! that helped!

Comment: I try not to spend time giving unhelpful answers.